# creating and outputting a global variable in ACF repeater block

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am trying to output all the titles of a repeater on a page  to appear inside a repeater block.  I can get it to output the values if they are static, but can't figure out how to get them to be the ACF repeater sub field instead.

I would like the output to look like:

```
<div class="repeated-block">
  <ul>
    <li>Title1</li><li>Title2</li><li>Title3</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Title1</h1>
</div>

<div class="repeated-block">
  <ul>
    <li>Title1</li><li>Title2</li><li>Title3</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Title2</h1>
</div>

<div class="repeated-block">
  <ul>
    <li>Title1</li><li>Title2</li><li>Title3</li>
  </ul>
  <h1>Title3</h1>
</div>
```

I **can** make it display static array titles using the method below, but I can't figure out how to make the array dynamically populated instead.  How would I get $foo to be an array of "the_sub_field('dynamic_title')"s  being the elements in the array instead?

```
function test() {
    $foo =  array("statictitle1","statictitle1","statictitle1");
    $arrlength=count($foo);
    echo "<ul>";
    for($x=0; $x < $arrlength; $x++)
    {
     echo "<li>" . $foo[$x] . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
<?php while ( have_rows('repeater_block') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <div class="repeated-block">
        <?php test(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_sub_field('dynamic_title'); ?></h1>
    </div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: why did you have 3 different repeaters?

Comment: check the ACF Documentation for Repeater first. Hopefully you can shorten your codes as well.

Comment: I only have 1 repeater in there - but the code might have been confusing.  Hopefully it makes more sense now